How to create material node instance?
I would like to create an instance of a color ramp, so that every parameter I modifiy in one node, that same parameter is modified in the instance. In 3ds max this is done with mapping controllers across different nodes.
Or how can I plug two image nodes into one color ramp? I doesn't work. Thanks


search for "Mix" node.

I'm not trying to mix any values,

Based on your screenshot you're trying to join two values into one, it's called mixing.

Please show me the material setup.

https://i.imgur.com/9BMNfzb.png

Yes I see what you mean. I'm still learning blender so connecting two images into one node isn't the way. I just need two instanced color ramps so the values are linked between them. I'm surprised that this is missing in blender.

Perhaps if you explained the effect you're going for, we could advise something. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

3ds max has hidden inputs for all material node values where you can input controller nodes and link them between different material nodes. So by changing the value in the controller node you change the value of every input that controller node is plugged into.
https://ibb.co/5Mz5z95
Do you know how can I achieve this in blender?
https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2024/ENU/3DSMax-Lighting-Shading/images/GUID-5E1C66FD-EBA8-4E9A-8486-339AC818E2F6.png

I don't know 3ds max, so I can't help, especially as on your sketch you have many-to-many relation, and on the 3ds max screenshot it's just one-to-one relation. Perhaps it works like portals

In 3dsmax it can be done just like I posted it in the image.  Been working in max many years.
